# django: import model mail field to a form resulting in SMTPRecipientsRefused error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to automatically send an email from a form in my django app. I need to access the email field from the following model:

```
class Client(TenantMixin):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(default='')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='') ###### username
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    auto_drop_schema = True
```

I need to use this field to use in the email function in the following form:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from customers.models import Client

class etl(forms.Form):
     ....
     def process_data(self, url, *args, **kwargs):
        ....
        sender_email = 'my_email@gmail.com'
        recipient_email = Client.email
        email_message = 'allez la test'
        
        subject = 'alerts'
        print(recipient_email)
        
        send_mail(subject, email_message, sender_email, [recipient_email])
```

this gives me the error:

```
SMTPRecipientsRefused at /upload.html {'"django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f11bdf4ada0"': (501, b'Invalid RCPT TO address provided')}
```

here is attached also my settings.py related to the issue

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'amazon-email'
EMAIL_PORT ='465'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'meItheuser'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

I am struggling with this error, I don't understand what could this be, when I hard write an email address it works fine and there is an email in the db to be access. Would someone has a clue of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `def Newform(forms.From):` makes no sense, since now you define a method (not a class), and thus it can not "subclass".

Comment: yes, I am aware it is a class, I have a bunch of stuff above this function and I figured it was the only part relevant to this question, let me edit to be a bit more explicit

Comment: I think the issue lies inside your Settings.py where you configured the mailer settings. Can you perhaps post them to make it easier to assist you?

Comment: yes sir, i post them right now

Comment: Vishal anything wrong coming from my email settings? they worked fine so far for everything related to password reseting stuff